# res.render not working as expected? doesn't load new pages

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use res.render to load a new page using handlebars, but it doesn't seem to working.

Here are my files:

main.js

```
var express = require("express");
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use('/static', express.static('public'));

var HTTP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

function onHttpStart() {
    console.log("Express http server listening on: " + HTTP_PORT);
}

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("home")
});

app.get("/roomList", function (req, res) {
   res.render('roomList')
});

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, onHttpStart);
```

Here's the main.handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/custom.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site</title>
</head>

<body>

    {{{body}}}

    <script src="/static/js/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/public/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When attempting to use res.render, nothing happens, despite there being html in `home.handlebars` and `roomList.handlebars`

Are there any steps I'm missing?
I have a default navbar in the main file, and it does stay when switching, but nothing new appears.

Comment: Could you show me your directory structure? Because it works perfectly in my case: https://imgur.com/gallery/NL7J2kW

Comment: @NadirAbbas Odd, here's my structure https://i.imgur.com/lGxOdqx.png

Comment: Forgot to open the dropdown menu but main.handlebars is in the layouts folder

Comment: Could it be a problem with the html i have in my body if it's not the structure?

Comment: Yes that is what I was about to say :p. Because if there is no error, that means Handlebars is loading the views.

Comment: weird, even after deleting the body from main, still doesn't work